# In Latin America, is "el ataque" or "la convulsión" more commonly used by medical professionals?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico, hispanoamérica, vocabulario-médico, costa-rica

My wife is a nurse and we're working on grammar for the next year or two before we travel extensively in Costa Rica. I'm putting together vocab lists and wondering what is more commonly used in a medical setting, "ataque" or "convulsión".

I would love any other medical specific resources you may have as well.

Edit: my apologies for not being specific, I was hoping for the one meaning seizures, sounds like convulsion is the better option.

Comment: I think the meaning of these two words is different.

Comment: It might help if you said what you think they both mean.

Comment: "ataque" is a very general word, and may refer to a heart attack, a nervous breakdown, a fit of cough, etc. "convulsión" will be usually used to refer to an epileptic seizure, or to the kind of shaking that accompanies a very high temperature.

Comment: You might want to add *infarto*  to your question.  If I understand it right it's more broad than the English *infarction*.

Comment: As @Gustavson points out ataque could be a wide variety of things, even a stroke (ataque cerebrovascular) although the more common form is accidente cerebrovascular. I would suggest the way forward is to look up the English word in Wikipedia and then click on the link down the left hand side which takes you to the corresponding Spanish form. This works less well on the mobile form of the site.

Comment: Words to the wise: Be very, very careful. You cannot just do this word for word and there are many false friends between Spanish and English. For example, careful with poisoning, poison and intoxication: https://www.npr.org/sections/health-shots/2014/10/27/358055673/in-the-hospital-a-bad-translation-can-destroy-a-life

Comment: I was hoping for the one meaning seizures, sounds like convulsion is the better option: you can say "convulsión" or "ataque (de epilepsia)", but "convulsión" is way more technical. "ataque" will only be understood as a seizure if the epileptic condition is implicit in the context or in the patient's clinical record.

Comment: Oh please, give us some context. What are you saying in English that is being translated??

Answer (score 1):

According to Mosby's Medical Dictionary (Spanish-English with E-S/S-E Vocabulary), the preferred term is `convulsión`.

I would recommend getting a Spanish-English medical dictionary. Mosby's is one of the most commonly used in Mexican faculties of medicine. I bet there're PDF versions somewhere on the internet ;)

S.A, *Diccionario Mosby (Inglés-Español, Español-Inglés) de Medicina*, Barcelona, Elsevier, 1a ed., 2008.